# Including AAR lib compile error: no resource identifier found

Tags: android, aar

I'm trying to make my own "lib" with Android Studio. I have generated aar file and included it to my test project. In my build.gradle I've added:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
} 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'mysdk_name', ext:'aar')
}
```

And in manifest of my test project I've added tools:replace="android:theme".
I can use classes from imported aar, but when I compile my project I'm getting errors:

```
Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fillColor' in package 'my_package_name'
Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'pageColor' in package 'my_package_name'
```

And so on. Here is my code from .aar project where errors appears:

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/tutorial_images_indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8"
    app:fillColor="@color/tutorial_pager_fill_color"
    app:pageColor="@color/tutorial_pager_page_color"
    app:radius="@dimen/dimen_4"
    app:strokeWidth="0dp"/>
```

What should I do to fix these errors?

**Edit:** That attibutes defined in external module that my main app uses.  I thought Android Studio will automaticly add that module to generated .aar, but I can't find that attrs inside .aar. So my question is how to include more than one module to .aar ?

Comment: The issue is that the attribute app:fillColor is not found, not the value!

Comment: [Gabriele Mariotti](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) I understand, but what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are these attributes defined in attrs.xml of your library?

Comment: These attributes are defined in module than my lib use. But I can't see that module inside my generated .aar. I thought Android Studio will automaticly include that modules to .arr if my main app is using them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I think I figured it out. My problem was that my .aar doesn't include resources from external modules. 
I've used [android-fat-aar](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar) script to solve this problem.